# How to reverse the order using connect by prior

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I have data like below:

```
 ID          DATA          S_LEVEL 
1304819     M02-004           1
1304819     M01-003           2
1304819     M01-005           3
1304819     MT-M01-005        4
1304819     M01-004           5
1304819     M01-002           6
1304819     M01-009           7
1304819     M01-020           8
1304819     MT-3100-007A      9
```

I want output like below using connect by prior and level:

```
 ID          DATA        S_LEVEL     D_LEVEL
1304819     M02-004         1           9
1304819     M01-003         2           8
1304819     M01-005         3           7
1304819     MT-M01-005      4           6
1304819     M01-004         5           5
1304819     M01-002         6           4
1304819     M01-009         7           3
1304819     M01-020         8           2
1304819     MT-3100-007A    9           1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` for D_level generate and apply order by

```
SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PARTID ORDER BY MAX (S_LEVEL) DESC) AS D_LEVEL
  FROM (SELECT PARTID, DATA, S_LEVEL FROM TABLE 
       ) 
  GROUP BY PARTID,DATA,S_LEVEL ORDER BY PARTID,S_LEVEL,D_LEVEL DESC
```

Comment: it works if I have only one unique ID. But for multiple IDs above query is not working.

Comment: Below query worked. 

SELECT A.*,
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PARTID ORDER BY MAX (S_LEVEL) DESC)
           AS D_LEVEL
  FROM (SELECT PARTID, DATA, S_LEVEL FROM TABLE       )
                                     GROUP BY PARTID,DATA,S_LEVEL
   ORDER BY PARTID,S_LEVEL,D_LEVEL DESC